# Detect IP regex C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have:

```
getObj("TextPPPIPAddress0").value="31.205.102.255";
```

I want get IP with Regex, I'm new with regex and I have conflict on ".
My code:

```
MatchCollection m1 = Regex.Matches(html, "getObj((\")TextPPPIPAddress0(\")).value=(\")(.+?)(\")", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

I want result 31.205.102.255

Comment: `\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b` will help

Comment: Why use regex in this case when you can simply use string split?  I like regex, but it often is used when string operation can be used.  String functions are give better performance (faster, less memory) than regex.  Should always use String function first, before regex.

Answer (score 5):

I would use

```
var ip = IPAddress.Parse(ipString);
```

`IPAddress` is in `System.Net` and already does what you want to do for you. You can use `TryParse()` if you want the boolean return value instead.

Comment: This is by far the best way, C# has some great built in stuff

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Regex ip = new Regex(@"\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b");
MatchCollection result = ip.Matches(getObj("TextPPPIPAddress0").value);
Console.WriteLine(result[0]);
```